# Bind events to properties and vice-versa in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I am rather new to bindings and WPF, but I've been able to do a few interesting things with bindings (interesting to me at least)

Does anyoine know if it's possible to bind an event (For example a SelectionChanged o Click event, etc) to a property (For example: IsChecked, IsEnabled, etc)?

I know I can bind properties with the Path property and all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to bind events to Commands you can do it through Attached Behavours. Have a look at [this blog](http://www.danharman.net/2011/08/05/binding-wpf-events-to-mvvm-viewmodel-commands/) as to how to do that with MVVM Light. Binding to `IsEnabled` does not make much sense

An example they give is:

```
<Button>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FooCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

In ViewModel

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    //set it as a toggle for example
    FooCommand = new RelayCommand( () => IsChecked = !IsChecked );
 }    

public ICommand FooCommand { get; private set; }

public bool  IsChecked
{
   get { return _isChecked; }
   set { _isChecked = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("IsChecked"); }
}
```

Comment: I know that binding to IsEnabled doesn't make sense, but I nedded an example. So this will alow me to bind events to commands. I will try that tomorrow and then I'll reply. Is there a way for me to use a Converter, or any of the other binding properties? Sorry for so many questions but bindings are extremely interesting, but rather confusing

Comment: Binding in WPF is Awesome... The reason you bind to commands is that the metaphor is the same. You can within the command implementation set another property value. I will update answer